# Chrome Extension desktop notification hide issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am using below code to show desktop notification via Chrome plugin:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
 'img/48.png',
 'my title',
 'some text here'
);

notification.show();
setTimeout(function(){
  notification.cancel();
}, 3000);
```

The notification is shown fine, however I want to hide it auto after some time through `setTimeout` but it does not hide, remain there. As per API, it has only two methods `show` and `cancel`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works fine for me. (Tested within a popup browser_action, popups closes correctly after 3 seconds)

Did you try setting a breakpoint to see whether the timeout actually fires?

Comment: It works but popup does not hide auto after 3 seconds, it never does.

Comment: As I said, hiding the popup after 3 seconds using `setTimeout` worked for me. Thus, could you check whether your timeout actually fires and notification.cancel() is called?